# Plugin Test fails with NPE

Tags: grails, spock

New to the grails testing, and trying to get a spock test to work in our application. The main grails application is not much more than a container for plugins which provide the real functionality.

So in one of the plugins, I created a functional test using spock.

```
package com.my.package

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(MessageController)
class MessageControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def "markMessageSent missing id should return 404"() {
        given:
        def result = controller.markMessageSent()
        expect:
        result.status = 404
    }
}
```

Error Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'contextPath' on null object.

I use this to run the tests:

```
grails -Dsis.type=colleague -Dserver.port=8001 test-app :spock
```

Ideas?

Comment: When you say functional test, is it under `test/functional`? Are you using [Geb](http://grails.org/plugin/geb) or only spock? Did you mean it is a simple unit test and placed under `test/unit`?

Comment: yup, under test/functional, and just vanilla spock, no Geb involved.

Comment: Then it actually is a unit test and should be under `test/unit`. Try with that refactor. I hope that should click.